# Numpy arrays somehow getting broken when encoding and writing to file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to store large numpy arrays inside files. To do this, I first generate them, then I call `array.tobytes()`, and finally I write it to a file.

Here is the example code I am using:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    val = 9 
    file = open("asdf.jkl", 'wb')
    array_1 = np.full((10, 10), val, dtype = "uint32")
    writelines = []
    print(array_1)

    for i in range(10):
        writelines.append(np.full((16, 16), i, dtype = "uint8"))
        writelines = [array_1.tobytes()] + writelines
    file.write("\n".encode('utf-8').join(writelines))
    file.close()
    
    with open("asdf.jkl", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        array_2 = np.fromstring(bytes(lines[0][:-1], "utf-8"), dtype = "uint32").reshape(10,10)
        print(array_2)
main()
```

The issue is this: if I give `val` a 1-digit value, it works well and does what is expected. However, if I give `val` anything above 9, it crashes with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "arrays.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "arrays.py", line 18, in main
    array_2 = np.fromstring(bytes(lines[0][:-1], "utf-8"), dtype = "uint32").reshape(10, 10)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (10,10)
```

Why the heck does it one time give the expected result, and then stop working on a whim? Why is array_2's size 0? What am I doing wrong?

Help would be much appreciated as I have been unable to solve this issue for the past 2 days. Thank you!

Comment: What does the file look like?

Comment: Without the `reshape$` I get a `array_2` shape as (100,).

Comment: Now try changing `val` to 12 or something. The file is basically filled with bytes (not really readable), and I believe that for `val` larger than 10 it for some reason splits the data on multiple lines as each line only has like 3 escape sequences (I have no idea what they mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are storing your data with `'\n'` as a separator; This will only work if `'\n'` doesn't appear anywhere in your actual data. The character `'\n'` is ASCII (or UTF-8) encoded as the number `10` (see https://www.asciitable.com/), so when you write out your array full of `10`s, it is equivalent to writing out a bunch of `'\n'`s. When you read the data in again, and split it on `'\n'`, it returns nothing (or nothing much) before the first `'\n'`, which is why it complains about trying to reshape an array of size 0.

When serializing your data to a file, you need a protocol to handle this sort of thing. Numpy already supports writing arrays to file, so if you just have one array, you should just use this (`numpy.save`). If you need to write a Python `list` to file (like you are doing here), maybe look at something like `pickle`.